# How can I extract image id from an API in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

So I have an app which uses Google Books API, and I have a div with image poster.
Thus i need to get image id from image url in Google API to change posters of books in these divs.

Javascript code:

```
const IMG_URL = "http://books.google.com/books/content?id="; //after "id=" I need to insert a particular image id
```

Function for showing books:

```
function showBooks(data){

    data.forEach(book => {
        const {title, authors, description} = book;
        const bookEl = document.createElement('div');
        bookEl.classList.add('book');

        bookEl.innerHTML = `
        <div class="border"></div>
        <img src="${IMG_URL + }">   //here I should concatenate url with book id
<div class="book_info">
        <h3>Book title</h3>
        <p>Author</p>
</div>
<div class="overview">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris mi augue, ultricies vitae nisi vitae, 
            suscipit elementum risus. Suspendisse vitae porta tellus, a finibus lorem. </p>
</div>
        
        
        
        `
    });
}
```

What it looks like in the API:

```
"thumbnail": "http://books.google.com/books/content?id=WvfgAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api"
```

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? To get `WvfgAAAAMAAJ` from this URL `http://books.google.com/books/content?id=WvfgAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=1&source=gbs_api` ?

Comment: @Reflective. no, my app is to search books by typing their title, so the contents in div should change, along with book poster
that's why i want to extract the image id to switch to any id of a book that's being searched

Answer (score 0):

I would construct a URL object and then extract the id parameter

```js
const url = new URL(yourImageUrl)
const id = url.searchParams.get("id")
```

Read more about the URL class here: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/URL